# How to pass string literal containing newlines to grep from bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to pass the "strings" from a file as input to `grep` using the `-F` (fixed string) parameter.

From `grep` the man page, the expected format is newline-separated:

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.
```

How can this be done in bash? I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
INFILE=$1
DIR=$2

# Create a newline-separated string array
STRINGS="";
while read -r string; do
    STRINGS+=$'\n'$string;
done < <(strings $INFILE);

cd $DIR
for file in *; do
    grep -Frn \"$STRINGS\" .
done;
```

But grep reports error at run-time regarding input formatting. Grep is interpreting the passed string arguments as parameters -- hence the need to pass them as one large string literal.

Debugging bash with `-x`and passing the first parameter (INFILE) as the script itself gives:

```
+ grep -Frn '"' '#!/bin/bash' 'INFILE=$1' 'DIR=$2' [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

inFile=$1
dir=$2

# Read all lines output by `string` into a single variable using
# a command substitution, $(...).
# Note that the trailing newlines is trimmed, but grep still recognizes
# the last line.
strings="$(strings "$inFile")"

cd "$dir"
for file in *; do
  grep -Frn "$strings" .
done
```

- `string` outputs each string found in the target file on its own line, so you can use its output as-is, via a command substitution (`$(...)`).

  - On a side note: `strings` is used to extract strings from *binary* files, and strings are only included if they're at least 4 ASCII(!) characters long and are followed by a newline or NUL.
    Note that while the [POSIX spec for `strings`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/strings.html) does mandate locale-awareness with respect to character interpretation, both GNU `strings` and BSD/macOS `strings` recognize 7-bit ASCII characters only.
  - If, by contrast, your search strings come from a *text* file from which you want to strip empty and blank lines, use `strings="$(awk 'NF>0' "$inFile")"`
- Double-quote your variable references and command substitutions to ensure that their values are used as-is.
- Do not use `\"` unless you want to pass a *literal* `"` char. to the target command - as opposed to an unquoted one that has *syntactical meaning* to *the shell*.

  - In your particular case, `\"$STRINGS\"` breaks down as follows:

    - An *unquoted* reference to variable `$STRINGS` - because the enclosing `"` are `\`-escaped and therefore *literals*.
    - The resulting string - `"<value-of-$STRINGS>"` - due to `$STRINGS` being *unquoted*, is then subject to [word-splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting)
      (and globbing), i.e., split into *multiple* arguments by whitespace. As a result, because `grep` expects the search term(s) as a *single* argument, the command breaks.
- Do not use all-uppercase shell variable names in order to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).